# why css class is not applied?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

could you please tell me why css class is not applied. ?

I `imported` my css `external` file this.
@import url("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eirikbakke/1059266/raw/d81dba46c76169c2b253de0baed790677883c221/gistfile1.css");

used like this

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="someclass">
      <h1 className="someclass">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-turing-x62pz?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: In react we use `className`

Comment: It's applied correctly, please check your console.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eirikbakke/1059266/raw/d81dba46c76169c2b253de0baed790677883c221/gistfile1.css". 
This is your trouble creator

Comment: what will be the solution

Answer (score 1):

That's because the external css file is being interpreted as text rather than a css file

`The resource from “https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eirikbakke/1059266/raw/d81dba46c76169c2b253de0baed790677883c221/gistfile1.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`

Comment: so what will be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**Important**: rawgit.com is shutting down. Read more about other alternatives here - https://rawgit.com/

So this is nothing to do with your code.One of the alternative is copy the gist url and paste it in https://raw.githack.com/ it will provide the link which you can use to run the example.

i used your link to get this link `https://gist.githack.com/eirikbakke/1059266/raw/d81dba46c76169c2b253de0baed790677883c221/gistfile1.css` applying this in ur css would work.

working sandbox [https://codesandbox.io/s/old-paper-lkdse]

Comment: Thanks sajan . can we remove `unused` css ..? I am not using `#someid` can we remove that

Comment: Yes you can remove that along with the comments in the file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GitHub allows to use its raw hosted files elsewhere and hence Github has blocked requests from Cross Domains.

It's a server-side configuration and you cannot enable CORS on Github servers.

An alternative way would be to host the file in some CDN or download the file and keep it locally.

**Another alternative I found was to download the contents of the file via JS and then append it as style element.**

Here is the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-davinci-f2nyr?file=/src/App.js) which works!

I never worked in React but I am sure you know better what would be the best place to keep the function that downloads the file.

```
function loadCssDynamically(fileUrl){
    // read text from URL location
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', fileUrl, true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
               var style = document.createElement('style');
               style.innerHTML = request.responseText;
               document.head.appendChild(style);
               // console.log(request.responseText);
               // return request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
}

var file = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eirikbakke/1059266/raw/d81dba46c76169c2b253de0baed790677883c221/gistfile1.css";
loadCssDynamically(file);
```